# While creating a first channel in hyperledger fabric, received error while bringing network down

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

So while creating my first channel using fabric samples test network as given in the documentation, I got an error while running `./network.sh down`

```
sh: cd: line 1: can't cd to /data: No such file or directory
sh: cd: line 1: can't cd to /data: No such file or directory
sh: cd: line 1: can't cd to /data: No such file or directory
```

I'm using windows 10 and feel like I've set up the paths correctly (at least those that were given in documentation). Any idea as to why this might be happening? 
docker 19.03.13
go 1.15.3
npm 6.14.6

Edit: I always get an error popup whenever I run any network.sh command first time after starting docker. i don't know whether it's relevant to the above question. I've attached a screenshot below
[Screenshot of popup warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogN2n.png)

Comment: Are you navigating into the right directory ? If you are trying to run test network for e.g the right command will be ```cd fabric-main-samples/test-network``` where the you will find the network.sh file then run it using ```./network.sh up```